# Number followed by any amount of [comma][number]

Tags: php, regex

Matching strings of unknown length - I'm taking an input from a user from a form.
The intended input is in the format `[number][comma][number][comma] etc...`
 An example of this input would be `3,43,1,238,24`.

The pattern can continue as long as the input allows, and any length number is accepted.

I'd like to use a regular expression to ensure that the user has formatted their entry correctly. First, I used str_replace to strip out any spaces within the response (just in case the user input spaces after the commas).

But I'm confused about how to match a pattern of unknown length. Would the following work?

```
/\d+,\d+/
```

I'm under the impression that this wouldn't work. It would only match the first two numbers in the pattern, and nothing after it. Any ideas?

If it matters, I'm using *PHP v 5.6.10*

Comment: Why not just try it our yourself: https://regex101.com/ ?! (https://regex101.com/r/cB4kJ4/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use something like `/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/`. This means:

```
^      # beginning of string
\d+    # one or more digits
(?:    # group (but don't capture)
  ,    #   a comma
  \d+  #   one or more digits
)*     # ... zero or more of this group
$      # end of string
```

This treats an input like `3,43,1,238,24` as a "head" (`3`) followed by (arbitrarily many) comma-number pairs (`,43` `,1` `,238` `,24`).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this pattern: `/(\d+)[^,]?+/gm`

https://regex101.com/r/gF1tO3/1

As PHP PCRE doesn't have the global (g) modifier, you should remove it and use `preg_match_all()`.

Example:

```
$str = '55, 44, 23 , 65 , 99,
234, 5 34,';

preg_match_all('/(\d+)[^,]?+/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: "I'd like to use a regular expression to ensure that the user has formatted their entry correctly." This answer doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: Hi @melpomene, I believe that with the solution I proposed he can capture the numbers from the input, even if the user entered spaces before or after the commas.

Comment: Yes, if the input is formatted correctly, your regex happens to sort of work to extract the numbers (what's `[^,]` supposed to do in there, though?). But the question was how to verify well-formedness, not to assume it. Your own example (`... 5 34,`) isn't valid according to the rules: There should be a comma between 5 and 34, and none at the end.